# Redirect when i submit?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Every time i click the submit button the page re-directs.

how can i set it up so that the page does not re-direct and it runs the server side code staying on the current page and echoing above my form?

HTML Code:

```
    <form name="contact_form" method="post" action="mail.php">
<table border="0">
<tbody class="Form">
<tr>
<td>
<label for="NameInput">Your Name:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
<input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="John Doe" id="NameInput" name="NameInput" required="required" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="CompanyName">Your Company:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
<input required="required" placeholder="Warner bros." id="CompanyName" name="CompanyName" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">Phone: </label>
<input placeholder="888-888-8888" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="Email" name="Email">Email:<font color="#FF0000">*</font></label>
<input required="required" placeholder="johndoe@gmail.com" id="Email" name="Email" type="email" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="Website">Website: </label>
<input placeholder="https://" id="Website" name="Website" />
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<p><strong>What interests you, broadly speaking?</strong></p>
<br/>

<p><input  id="WebDesignCheckbox" name="WebDesignCheckbox" type="checkbox">Web Design/Development</input></p>

<input id="SocialMediaCheckbox" name="SocialMediaCheckbox" type="checkbox">Social Media</input>
>
<input id="MobilePresence" name="MobilePresence" type="checkbox">Mobile Presence</input>

<input id="OnlineAdvertising" name="OnlineAdvertising" type="checkbox">Online Advertising</input>

<input id="SEOCheckbox" name="SEOCheckbox" type="checkbox">Search Engine Optamization</input>

<p><input id="ecommerceCheckbox" name="ecommerceCheckbox" type="checkbox" >eCommerce</input></p>

<br/>


<label for="comments">Your Ideas to Life?</label><br/>
<textarea placeholder="How can we help you?" id="comments" name="comments" style="margin: 2px; height: 137px; width: 437px;"></textarea></td></tr><br/>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" align="middle" /></td>
</tr>
<p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>
</form>
```

PHP Script mail.php:

```
<?php  
if( isset($_POST) ){  

    //form validation vars  
    $formok = true;  
    $errors = array();  

    //sumbission data  
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    $date = date('d/m/Y');  
    $time = date('H:i:s');  

    //form data  
    $NameInput = $_POST['NameInput'];      
    $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];  
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];  
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];  
    $Website = $_POST['Website'];
    $WebDesignCheckbox = $_POST['WebDesignCheckbox'];
    $SocialMediaCheckbox = $_POST['SocialMediaCheckbox'];
    $MobilePresence = $_POST['MobilePresence'];
    $OnlineAdvertising = $_POST['OnlineAdvertising'];
    $SEOCheckbox = $_POST['SEOCheckbox'];
    $ecommerceCheckbox = $_POST['ecommerceCheckbox'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];  

    //form validation
    if(empty($NameInput)){
        $formok - false;
        $errors[] =  "You have not entered a name.";
    }

    if(empty($CompanyName)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a company name.";
    }

    if(empty($Email)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address.";
    }

    //send email if checks out
    if($formok){
        ini_set("sendmail_from","keeano@doodleinc.co");
        /*$headers="From: Contact Page: {$Email}" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";*/
        $emailbody = "
        <p>Time: {$time} \n {$date}</p>
        <p>You are recieving this from your websites contact form.</p>
        <p><strong>Contacts Name: </strong> {$NameInput}</p>
        <p><strong>Companys Name: </strong> {$CompanyName}</p>
        <p><strong>Phone Number: </strong> {$PhoneNumber}</p>
        <p><strong>Email: </strong> {$Email}</p>
        <p><strong>Website: </strong> {$Website}</p>
        <p><strong>Web Design Checkbox: </strong> {$WebDesignCheckbox}</p>
        <p><strong>Social Media Checkbox: </strong> {$SocialMediaCheckbox}</p>
        <p><strong>Mobile Presence: </strong> {$MobilePresence}</p>
        <p><strong>Online Advertising: </strong> {$OnlineAdvertising}</p>
        <p><strong>SEO Checkbox: </strong> {$SEOCheckbox}</p>
        <p><strong>eCommerce Checkbox: </strong> {$ecommerceCheckbox}</p>
        <p><strong>Comments: </strong> {$comments}</p>
        <p><strong>Extra Data Obtained:</strong>\n Users IPAddress: {$ipaddress}</p>
        ";
        mail("keeano@doodleinc.co", "Contacts Page Enquiry", $emailbody);

        echo('<p style="font-weight: bold; color: #709900"><em>Thank you for contacting doodle Inc., someone will contact you within 48 hours.</em></p>');
    }
}
```

I would simply like to get this to create a label at the top of the Form saying "Thank you, someone will be in touch with you within 48 hours."

If someone can help me that would be great as well as detail the explanation so i never run into this problem again.

Comment: You have set form action to mail.php,  thats why it redirects to mail.php on clicking submit button.

Comment: When you submit the form by pressing the submit button inside the form, the action attribute `action="mail.php"` redirects you to the page specified as obvious.

Comment: okay, so how do i get it to run the code when submitted but not re-direct?

Comment: To stay on the same page and do not reload anything, you have to post your content by Ajax

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you have `mail.php` as your action for the form tag.
you could just leave it blank, then the form will post to the same page (contact.php)

To get the functionality working on that page you could include your `mail.php` file before the form, so that the errors are displayed on that same page.
just a `require("mail.php");` at the top of the code will do.

Comment: <?php require("mail.php") ?> Before the form makes my form dissapear?

Comment: it shouldn't. the `mail.php` should only execute if `$_POST` is sent otherwise it just ignores the if statement.

Comment: could we chat so i can get it figured out? im not the best with php.

Comment: I have tried every form of require 'mail.php' and it either crashes the whole page or just the form.How can submitting a little information be so difficult!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at doing a javascript event on the submit button. Then use json and ajax to process your form etc, return a success/fail message, and insert into where the form was. This will not 'redirect' the user to a different page, the form will get replaced by a success message.

```
<form method="get" action="" onsubmit="jsquickcomp(this); return false;" > // or something like this for your form heading.
```

Then you js function....

```
function jsquicksub(po_form) {

    if (gb_ajaxbusy)
        return false;

    gb_ajaxbusy = true;

    var lo_request = {};
    lo_request.n = $(po_form).find('#sub-firstname').val();
    lo_request.e = $(po_form).find('#sub-email').val();
// etc etc

    $(po_form).fadeTo(200, 0.3);

    $.getJSON('/mail.php', lo_request, function(po_result) { // this is your mail.php which performs all the php side of the form stuff

        gb_ajaxbusy = false;
        $(po_form).fadeTo(0, 1);

        if (!po_result.success) {
            alert(po_result.content); // has an alert box for error message. Can change it for anything
            return false;
        }else{
            setTimeout(function() { 
                    $.modal.close();
            }, 2500);
        }

        $(po_form).replaceWith(po_result.content); // replaces the form with the success message

    });

}
```

Then in your mail.php

```
// function gets passed values after validation and returns a message to the user on screen
function jsonreturn($pb_success, $ps_content = null) {

    $lo_result = (object) array('success'=>$pb_success, 'content'=>$ps_content);

    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode($lo_result);
    exit;

} // end jsonreturn()

// use $_GET to get all the values you have send through from your js file
// validate the data and do whatever you want to do with it

// these return the message that will replace the form
jsonreturn(true, 'Success!'); // for success
jsonreturn(false, 'Fail'); // for fail
```

Hope that makes some sense?